# "Value of type '(CLLocationManager, [CLLocation]) -> ()' has no member 'delegate' " Error in swift with mapping

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

When trying to find the location of a user, I use `CLLocationManager`. Where I have this line:

```
locationManager.delegate = self
```

It returns this error:

> Value of type '(CLLocationManager, [CLLocation]) -> ()' has no member ‘delegate'

Here is the code:

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox

class MapsViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
            locationManager.delegate = self //this is where I get the error said above
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }
}
```

I have tried the error on stackoverflow and solving it myself, but nothing has helped so far. It might be a problem with the new version of Swift & Xcode (as I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDrdtdMYgWc) tutorial)

I add `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description` and `Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description` in `Info.plist` for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
class MapsViewController: UIViewController,MGLMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
```

Answer (score 1):

[Sh_Khan’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59571584/1271826) is correct, but I might suggest pulling the conformance to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol into its own extension:

```
extension MapsViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
        guard let coordinate = locations.last?.coordinate else { return }

        print("locations = \(coordinate.latitude) \(coordinate.longitude)")
    }
}
```

Separating protocol conformance from the base class implementation  keeps code nicely organized and enables code folding (e.g. <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>◄</kbd>). For a view controller this small it doesn’t matter, but as the code for this view controller grows, it’s really convenient to use extensions to organize it.

See [Adding Protocol Conformance with an Extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID277) in *The Swift Programming Language.*